# How to get userid in Django classviews?

Tags: python, django

I  have this class that changes user password:

```
class PasswordsChangeView(PasswordChangeView):
from_class = PasswordChangingForm

success_url = reverse_lazy(
    "base:password/passwordsuccess",
)
```

And I would like to insert User Avatar Img Path in context.

This Img is inside a UserComplement model.

When I create function views, it works doing:

```
@login_required
def password_success(request):
    try:
        obg = UserComplement.objects.get(pk=request.user.id)
        context = {
            "img_avatar": obg.avatar_image,
        }
        return render(request, "registration/passwordsuccess.html", context)
    except UserComplement.DoesNotExist:
        return render(request, "registration/passwordsuccess.html")
```

The problem is that I cannot get the userID in classviews to pass it through the context on success_url.

Comment: Do you mean that your `success_url` needs to reverse a url that has the user id in it?

Comment: Yes.

I have to pass the avatarpath in a variable. This avatar path is in the database, accessed by UserComplement model.

So, when I try to create the variable in which should contain the avatarPath, i need the current user.id.

Using functionView, I can do:

variable = UserComplement.objects.get(pk=request.user.id)

But when I inherit PasswordChangeView, I cant access request.user.id to specify pk = request.user.id to search the avatarImage path....

How can I access the request and after the variable in the webpage? How to pass this context without render function?

Answer (score 1):

It was a lack of knowledge on how class based views work. The function get_context_data did the job well, returning the context.

```
class PasswordsChangeView(PasswordChangeView):
    from_class = PasswordChangingForm

    success_url = reverse_lazy(
        "base:password/passwordsuccess",
    )

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        obj = UserComplement.objects.get(pk=self.request.user.id)
        context["img_avatar"] = obj.avatar_image
        return context
```

Comment: Glad you found it :)  Here is a useful site for exploring Django's class-based views (which can be a pain to understand just from reading the src code) https://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/4.0/django.contrib.auth.views/PasswordChangeView/